# How to make a proper test using Browserstack, selenium and mocha?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, browserstack

I'm trying to learn to test my web apps with browserstack.
I'm running their example from their website

```
var assert = require('assert'),
  fs = require('fs');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
  test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');

test.describe('Google Search', function() {
  var driver, server;

  test.before(function() {
  var capabilities = {
    'browserName' : 'firefox', 
    'browserstack.user' : 'my username',
    'browserstack.key' : 'my key'
   }
  driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer('http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub').
    withCapabilities(capabilities).
    build();
  });

  test.it('should append query to title', function() {
    driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('BrowserStack');
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
    driver.wait(function() {
      return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        return 'BrowserStack - Google Search' === title;
      });
    }, 1000);
  });

  test.after(function() { driver.quit(); });
});
```

and it gives me this input

Google Search
    1) "before all" hook

0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

1) Google Search "before all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

I've tried to run my own test

```
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('fs');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
describe('Google Search', function(){
    var driver;
    var server;
    var capabilities = {
        'browserName' : 'firefox', 
        'browserstack.user' : 'myuser',
        'browserstack.key' : 'mykey'
    }
    before(function(done){
        driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .usingServer('http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub')
            .withCapabilities(capabilities)
            .build();
        done();
    });
    after(function(){
        driver.quit();
    });
    describe('Here we go', function(){
        it('Should do something', function(done){
            driver.get('http://www.google.ro').then(done);
            // done();
        })
    });
})
```

and it gives me this output

```
      Google Search
    Here we go
      1) Should do something


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Google Search Here we go Should do something:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

When I comment driver.get it works ok... but I kinda need it..

So how can I make a functional test ? 
I cannot find anything on google..

Comment: What happens if you use the same general code but instead of starting a session on BrowserStack, you run a local browser? Does it work?

Comment: if i run locally it does the same thing. and the test finished right before the browser is opened

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the default timeout is too low for Selenium. You should increase it to 30 seconds :

```
mocha mocha-spec.js --timeout 30000
```

You could also set the timeout in your script:

```
before(function(done){
    this.timeout(30000);

    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .usingServer('http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub')
        .withCapabilities(capabilities)
        .build();
    done();
});
```